# When words are brothers

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> A direction opposite wrongness
>   Double Vee at front, wings are made
>   Toul minus ghoul, a magic letter minus what you gain—
>   add what comes of it, paper is used.
>   Remove Vee one by one,
>   the passage is a ceremony so holy.
>   Whatever may be the case,
>   we all sound the same.

What on earth is the point of origin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> Right

A direction opposite wrongness

> **Right** is the opposite of wrong

Double Vee at front, wings are made

> The (double v = w) **wright** brothers (hence the title) made the first aircraft

Toul minus ghoul, a magic letter minus what you gain---

> $t+o+u+l-(g+h+o+u+l)=-gh+t$ which tells us to add letter `t` in place of `gh`. Technically, we gain the letter `t` and lose the letters `g`, `h`. Magic `e` $-$ letter gained `t` = $-t+e$ which means that magic `e` (which can only be the last letter of a word) will replace the `t` (which ends `wright`).

add what comes of it, paper is used

> Paper is used to **write** things (homophone)

Remove Vee one by one,
the passage is a ceremony so holy.

> A (-w)**rite** is a spiritual ceremony - a rite of passage

Whatever may be the case,
we all sound the same.

> Right, Wright, write and rite sound the same

Answer (score 3):

My first time answering so go easy!

A direction opposite wrongness

> Right (Self explanatory)

Double Vee at front, wings are made

> Wright (Wright Brothers)

Toul minus ghoul,
a magic letter minus what you get---

> Wight (A type of creature sometimes a ghost/spirit)

add what comes of it, paper is used.

> Write (Write on paper)

Remove Vee one by one,

> Blight (A disease?)

the passage is a ceremony so holy.

> Rite (A ritual)

Whatever may be the case,

> Flight (Flight case)

we all sound the same.

> This is how I chose the above answers, they all rhyme. I can't think of a rhyming answer for this last section though.

What on earth is the point of origin?

> I'm assuming you don't want a literal place looking as previous comments. You asked "Which word marks the start of the wordplay?" which would be either "A" or the answer, which is "Right".

Comment: Welcome to PSE! It's my first in wordplay as well! Wordplay is a specific kind of puzzle, and this is my first attempt at it. Many of the explanations don't fit, but this is your first time---so don't worry. It's an excellent answer. +1! Keep solving puzzles and keep learning! Hopefully, you'll get much better with practice. Also, you're expected to provide a little more explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will try and give more in depth explanations in future. Of course practice makes perfect!

Comment: Welcome. It's everyone's responsibility to make newcomers feel at home. Anyways, not every line of the sentence necessarily yields a different word or idea. Multiple lines often work as a whole to convey a singular word/idea. Keep that in mind, while solving puzzles.

Comment: The riddle has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. This is a tough one. I have only stabs in the dark...

*Ghoul minus tool* - A gravedigger or graverobber without his tool, e.g., a spade or shovel, would not be able to work--he would no longer be regarded as a *wright* (from Old English *wryhta*, worker.)

Thus, a *wright*, minus his necessary *tool* for work, loses the 'gh' that made him a wright, and is left with *writ* (past tense/past participle of *write*).

~~

*right* and *rite* both involve acting in an upright, straight, proper manner, with etymological roots in:

Greek, *orektós* - upright;

Latin, *rēctus* - accurate, righteous, correct, straight, virtuous;

Latin, *rītus* - rite, custom, ceremony, fashion, sacramental, consuetude.

~~

That's all I've got so far. - I have to go, but I'll come back to at least cite my references for the above, and perhaps another idea will percolate up from my subconscious!

Comment: Hmm... interesting observations. But your approach is not likely to work. It's totally understandable, as you're new to PSE. This is my first try at wordplay, a specific kind of puzzles which is basically playing with words. Anyways, as your first answer, it was wonderful! Loved your ideas! +1

Comment: The riddle has been updated.